# kubeadm has a empty token list

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I'm running a k8s cluster to study and when I run kubeadm token list on the master node doesn't do anything, just jump to another line. And there is no file /etc/kubernetes/pki/tokens.csv on the master node.

```
root@k8s-master:~# kubeadm token list -v=5
I0825 17:36:25.542891  400954 cmdutil.go:81] Using kubeconfig file: /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
I0825 17:36:25.544288  400954 token.go:368] [token] preparing selector for bootstrap token
I0825 17:36:25.544557  400954 token.go:378] [token] retrieving list of bootstrap tokens
```

I just want to know why it is happening?

Thanks for any help!